# SQL Server 2008 SQL Query to retrieve 'working week' (Tuesday to Tuesday)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There are quite a few posts on this topic, but we are still struggling to get some SQL that works for the period and the posts are just confusing.

What we want to do is return all records where timestamp is >= start of working week which is a Tuesday. Could someone advise where we are going wrong.

i.e Yesterday it was 27th October, so when we ran our query it would return all results from 21st October (the previous Tuesday). Today it is 28th, so when we now run our query, it will only return results from the 28th. Tomorrow when we run it, we will get 28th and 29th....etc.

```
timestamp >= dateadd(day, -4-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Note: this query worked fine when we ran it yesterday, so I am wondering if it changes by the day?

Comment: `-4-<...>`, where `<...>` is a positive integer, can never produce the value of `0` that you need today.

Comment: `dateadd(day, -4+datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))`

Comment: @artm That cannot be right. `-4+datepart(dw, getdate())` can produce positive values, but the OP clearly never needs a positive result.

Comment: Mod 7 would be OK, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod 7 please:

```
select 
    dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, getdate() ) + 4)%7, getdate())
   ,dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, '2014-10-28' ) + 4)%7, '2014-10-28')  --2014-10-28
   ,dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, '2014-10-27' ) + 4)%7, '2014-10-27')  --2014-10-21
   ,dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, '2014-10-29' ) + 4)%7, '2014-10-29')  --2014-10-28
```

**UPDATE**

According to @hvd's comment, when we use these approach, we assuming the start day of week is Sunday by default of U.S.English. Further information in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

`SET DATEFIRST 7` can ensure this approach to be correct.

Comment: Hi there, when I run the first line in the code, (dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, getdate() ) + 4)%7, getdate())) The query runs fine (i.e. it returns only dates from the 28th onwards). Can you confirm that this formula *should* continue to work for other days as per my initial post? Thanks and I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just a warning: this relies on Sunday being considered the first day of the week, which is the default on English systems, but can be configured differently and is not necessarily the default on other systems. It's probably not a problem for the OP, but it deserves to be mentioned for the benefit of other readers who come here looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: @italian_homes Year I'm sure, but suggest you to test more dates with replacing date value to `getdate()` like the other lines in my code sample.

Comment: The requirement for this slightly changed.Ifthe FIRST day of the reporting week (i.e 28) then we need all results from the PREVIOUS reporting wk (i.e. 21-27). For all other days, the query works fine. I am not sure if I have updated my SQL correctly, is it possible to test this without trying it every single day?convert(varchar,datesdetailed.Dates.shiftdate,112) >=  
(case when -(datepart(dw, getdate() ) + 4)%7=0 then dateadd(day, -4-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
else convert(varchar,dateadd(day, -(datepart(dw, getdate() ) + 4)%7, getdate()),112)
end)

Comment: It's necessary to test for some single days(only about 50 FIRST days of weeks in a year, not too much :). And if you want previous start day from current start day of week, just `case when (datepart(dw, getdate() ) + 4)%7=0 then dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Finally understood your points, you should provide an extra parameter here to point out which day is the beginning of working week, then it will be easy to calculate the days

Comment: "How do get the beginning of the working week?" "Let code pass the beginning of the working week as a parameter." Seriously? How do you not see that this just shifts the problem to "How do I write the code to determine the beginning of the working week in order to pass it as a parameter?"